# mirror modifier kinda glitch

Tags: mirror

i think this is a glitch or something.
i bought the Blender Game Asset Creation for my left over money on steam so i cant really get help there so i ask here instead.
i am stuck on the Blender: 5.2 UVs - Mirror Modifier video and this always seems to happen when i mirror the traffic cone.

Before adding the modifier:
[image]
After adding the modifier:
[image]

someone pls help i am a pretty noob in blender and i understand that this might be very easy.

Comment: More than likely you rotated the object in object mode and need to apply transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating an object can make the mirror axis un-intuitive. You can see current rotation in the transform panel, which is opened with <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D viewport . You should apply rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then it will behave like you expect.